# asp net mvc индикатор загрузки файлов проблема с HttpPostedFileBase=null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть в представлении форма с загрузкой файлов на сервер. Хочу прикрутить индикатор загрузки, чтобы было понятно, что что-то грузиться...

Просмотрев разные источники. решил делать используя jquery.
В контроллере:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data",id="proc",name="proc" }))
            {
                <p>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="upload"/>                        
                    <input type="submit" name="operation" id="process" value="process" />                        
                </p>
            }                   <div id="divProcessing">
        <p>Идет загрузка файла, пожалуйста подождите . . . <img src="../../Content/ajax-loader.gif"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="divResult">
    </div>
```

....

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $("#divProcessing").hide();
        $("#proc").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();                
            $("#divProcessing").show();
            var url = $(this).attr("action");
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (resp) {                        
                    $("#divProcessing").hide();                        
                    $("<h3>Загружено"</h3>").appendTo("#divResult");
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>}
```

В контроллере:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{}
```

И здесь проблема, файл выбираю, нажимаю на кнопку, но в контроллере HttpPostedFileBase=null, при этом скрипт выполняется и вижу индикатор. Если в представлении .BeginForm удаляю id и name - в контроллер файл передается, но скрипт соответственно не срабатывает, индикатора нет.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос. Во вьюхе

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", **id = "fileUpload"** }))
            {
                <p>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="upload" value="Загрузка квитанции" style="background-color:firebrick;color:white" />
                    @ViewBag.Message <br />              
                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="btnFileUpload" style="background-color:firebrick;color:white;width:370px">Загрузить</button>
                </p>
            } <div id="container" style="color:red;text-align:center;font-size:18px">
    <p>Пожалуста подождите, идет загрузка квитанций...<img src="../../Content/ajax-loader.gif"></p>
</div>
```

скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#container").hide();
            $("#btnFileUpload").click(function () {
                $("#container").show();
                var formData = new FormData();
                var file = document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0];
                formData.append("fileInput", file);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "Home/Upload",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,                        
                    success: function (resp) {
                        $("#container").hide();
                        $("<h3>Загрузка квитанций завершена</h3>").appendTo("#divResult");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```